# SVG has Fill of Black instead of mapped Color

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a plot with many svg rects in my [block](http://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/99a123aae5e3819dbe835a14d0f2f175). Most I were able to plot and fill just fine, however the initial rect is not blue like it is in my color map:

```
var colorMap = {
  0: "blue",
  1: "red",
  2: "yellow",
};
```

`console.log()` shows that the correct integer is being passed, and the correct color is being associated by the object. The other columns in my csv are floats, but the values for my color map are integers. The column has the header of `id` and takes on 1 of 3 values: 0,1 or 2.

I have read that this error can occur when the number is a float, not an integer. But to my knowledge, they are all integers. And even if my 0 entry is not an integer (for whatever reason) then why are all the other entries in that column working just fine? That would be very counter intuitive to have D3 recognize some numbers as floats and others as integers within the same exact column.

Perhaps it's not about integers/floats at all, could I be overlooking something else?

Comment: have you tryed with hex values instead of color names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript (as well as all languages I'm aware of) `0` is falsy, that is, it evaluates to `false`. The [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) are:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- 0
- `NaN`
- "" (empty string)

That being said, this:

```
.style('fill', function(d) {
    var colorID = d.id;
    if (colorID) {
        return colorMap[colorID];
    }
});
```

... will evaluate to `false` when `colorID` is zero, and therefore it will avoid you to use the `colorMap` when `d.id` is zero.

Solution: just drop it:

```
.style('fill', function(d) {
    return colorMap[d.id];
});
```

Or, alternatively, if your intention is just to check if the property exists:

```
.style('fill', function(d) {
    var colorID = d.id;
    if (colorID != undefined) {
        return colorMap[colorID];
    }
});
```

Here is your updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/932089f945d5930ef8e7d8060b0d0bfe

Comment: Thats really interesting, thanks for bringing it to my attention. I had put it there to avoid na errors with other data sets, now I guess I will go with `!=undefined` as you suggested.